# To change Background Color and pick value of pressed Keys

Tags: jquery, css

I Have created a Numeric Keypad. On press of Numeric Key I want to change Background Color of 'li span' elements that are in 'enteredPin' DIV one by one. The Value of Numeric Keys will go in hidden Password field.
What should be Jquery?

```
<div id="showNumPad">
                <ul id="enteredPin"class="pin-list">
                    <li><span></span></li>
                    <li><span></span></li>
                    <li><span></span></li>
                    <li><span></span></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="keypad-container">
                    <ul id="numberList">
                        <li><span>1</span></li>
                        <li><span>2</span></li>
                        <li><span>3</span></li>
                        <li><span>4</span></li>
                        <li><span>5</span></li>
                        <li><span>6</span></li>
                        <li><span>7</span></li>
                        <li><span>8</span></li>
                        <li><span>9</span></li>
                        <li><span>0</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

/* CSS is HERE/*

.pin-list{ width:100%; float:left; text-align:center;}
.pin-list li{ display:inline-block;}
.pin-list li span{ width:15px; height:15px; display:inline-block; border:solid 1px #fff; border-radius:50%; margin:7px;}

.keypad-container{ width:100%; float:left; margin:10px 0;}
.keypad-container ul{ width:99%; display:inline-block; text-align:center;}
.keypad-container ul li{ display:inline-block; margin:7px 10px;}
.keypad-container ul li span{ width:60px; height:60px; display:inline-block; border-radius:50%; color:#fff; border:solid 1px #fff; text-align:center; line-height:60px; font-size:25px; cursor:pointer;}
.keypad-container ul li span:hover, .keypad-container ul li span:active, .keypad-container ul li span:focus{ background:#fff; color:#000;}
```

Comment: Can you please describe your question more..
Means on clicking on <li><span>1</span></li> you want change color of all  li span inside enteredPin

Comment: @JyotiSharma as there are 4 Span in 'enteredPin' so my PIN is of 4 digits, when user press first time then first span will highlighted and so on.

Comment: Ok give me some time. will resolve your question

Comment: Hello, Please check following code on jsfiddle URL.  which I have provided in answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `<input type="hidden" name="vPassword" id="vPassword" value="">` in your HTML.

Please provide following js

```
$(document).on("click","#numberList li span",function(){
     var js_password = $("#vPassword").val();
     var enter_pin_length = js_password.length;
     if(enter_pin_length <= 3){
         var eleObj = $("#enteredPin li span").get(enter_pin_length);
         $(eleObj).css('background',"red");
         $("#vPassword").val(js_password + $(this).text());
     }
});
```

Please find answer on following  URL : https://jsfiddle.net/0pdL71m2/25/

Comment: Thanks. If I have a delete button having id "deletePin" how I can Delete entered Pin number one by one, so that user can reenter. That mean I have to change color of 'enteredPin' again.

Comment: Ok I will provide that code below of that one.. :)
You want to delete one by one or directly complete password.?

Comment: I want to delete one by one

Comment: I have provide deletePin Code also on:
https://jsfiddle.net/0pdL71m2/27/ 
Please check It.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of how to target the entered pin `li`:

css:

```
.entered{
    background-color: red;
}
```

js:

```
$('#numberList').find('li').on('click', function() {
    $('#enteredPin').find('li').not('.entered').eq(0).addClass('entered');
});
```